# why when I use axios to post data to my mongodb cloud I got an object with _id and empty fields?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, axios

I made a react app and I can read data by axios.get() and I can delete data as well in the app, but the problem is I can't post data to my MongoDB cloud? any help, please.

I made a MongoDB cloud database as shown here.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
      extended: true
}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://Admin-Ali:AAssppmm11@cluster0.d0joo.gcp.mongodb.net/visualizor", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ArticaleSchema = new Schema({ title: String, tags: String }, { strict: false })
var Articale = mongoose.model("Article", ArticaleSchema);
// const articals = new Articale({ title: "title", tag: "h1" })
// articals.save();
//1. get Fetch all articals
app.get("/articals", (req, res) => {
      Articale.find((err, foundArticals) => {
            res.send(err ? err : foundArticals)
      })
})

//2. post (Create One new Artical.)
app.post("/articals", (req, res) => {
      new Articale(req.body).save((err) => { res.send(err ? err : req.body) })
})


//3.delete all the articals.
app.delete("/articals", (req, res) => {
      Articale.deleteMany((err) => {
            res.send(req.body);
      })

})
app.route("/articals/:articleTitle")
      .get((req, res) => {
            Articale.findOne({ title: req.params.articleTitle },
                  (err, foundArticle) => { res.send(err ? err : foundArticle) })
      })
      .put((req, res) => {

            Articale.update({ _id: req.params.articleTitle },
                  { title: req.body.title }, { overwrite: true },
                  (err) => { res.send(err ? err : `${req.params.articleTitle}` + " Updated") })
      })
      .patch((req, res) => {
            Articale.update({ _id: req.params.articleTitle }, { $set: req.body },
                  (err) => { res.send(err ? err : "Articale: " + `${req.params.articleTitle}` + " updatted") })
      })
      .delete((req, res) => {
            Articale.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.articleTitle },
                  (err) => { res.send(err ? err : `${req.params.articleTitle}` + " Has deleted") })
      })

app.listen(5000, function () {
      console.log("Server started on: http://localhost:5000/");
});
```

then on other file

```
const api = axios.create({ baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/articals" })
api.post("/", { title: "update", tag: "h1" })
```

then I get
{
"_id": "5f2046a176af4d190018beea",
"__v": 0
}

---

Also when I use postman body, row and enter {title:"XX"
tag:"h1"} I got the same issue.
But when I use postman body, x-www-form-urlencoded and post data in it I got my data in the cloud without any problem?
Note: I use allow CORS access control chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

```
const qs = require('querystring')    

axios.post("/" , qs.stringify( { title: "update", tag: "h1" }), {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
 })
```

try this.

Comment: also this would help you https://gist.github.com/akexorcist/ea93ee47d39cf94e77802bc39c46589b .

Comment: thank you so much it worked. I don't understand what is x-ww-form-urlencoded do, but it worked.
the solution can work like this as well.

import axios from "axios"`
import qs from "query-string"

const api = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/articals", headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
})

api.post("/", qs.stringify({ title: "update", tag: "h1" }))
```